Unable to find an element with the text in React Testing Library with Ant Design Dropdown
I'm working on a React application that uses Ant Design for UI components and Redux for state management. I'm writing tests using React Testing Library, but I'm having trouble interacting with a dropdown (Select component) from Ant Design.
Here is the relevant part of my component:
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Form, Select } from 'antd';
import { loadMasterDatatoFA, clearCategoryAttributeMapping, resetAllFunctionalAreaFormValues, loadDoctypeAttributes } from '../Actions';
import { functionalAreas, apFieldMapping, OPENTEXT_ENTITY_CODE, CATNAME } from "../Constants";
import { getEntityCode } from '../Utils';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import FormItemsGenerator from '../../FormItemGenerator/FormItemGenerator';

const FormItem = Form.Item;

export const AP = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const functionalAreasState = useSelector(state => state.functionalAreas);
    const { apFormValues, selectedFA, categoryDoctypeMapping, categoryAttributeMapping } = functionalAreasState;
    const { selectedApplication, entityFunctionalAreas } = useSelector(state => state.landingScreen);
    const selectedEntityCode = getEntityCode(selectedApplication, entityFunctionalAreas);
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(loadMasterDatatoFA(selectedEntityCode, selectedApplication, selectedFA, entityFunctionalAreas));
        if (selectedEntityCode === OPENTEXT_ENTITY_CODE) {
            dispatch(clearCategoryAttributeMapping());
            dispatch(resetAllFunctionalAreaFormValues());
        }
    }, [selectedApplication, selectedFA]);

    const handleCategoryChange = useCallback(value => {
        updateState(functionalAreas.AP, CATNAME, apFormValues, value, dispatch);
        if (value) {
            dispatch(loadDoctypeAttributes(selectedApplication, functionalAreas.AP, entityFunctionalAreas, value, t));
        } else {
            dispatch(clearCategoryAttributeMapping());
        }
    }, [functionalAreas.AP, CATNAME, apFormValues, dispatch, selectedApplication, entityFunctionalAreas, t]);

    const otFormItems = useMemo(() => [
        <FormItem name="apCategoryList" label={'Category'} key={CATNAME} required>
            <Select
                data-testid={'ap-category-selector'}
                placeholder={'Select a Category'}
                allowClear
                value={apFormValues[CATNAME]}
                onChange={handleCategoryChange}
            >
                {categoryDoctypeMapping?.map(category => (
                    <Select.Option data-testid={'category'} key={category.categoryId} value={category.categoryId.toString()}>
                        {category.categoryName}
                    </Select.Option>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormItem>,
        <FormItemsGenerator
            key="formItemsGenerator"
            categoryAttributeMapping={categoryAttributeMapping}
            formValues={apFormValues}
            updateState={updateState}
            functionalArea={functionalAreas.AP}
            dispatch={dispatch}
            selectedApplication={selectedEntityCode}
        />
    ], [categoryDoctypeMapping, apFormValues, handleCategoryChange, categoryAttributeMapping, selectedEntityCode]);

    return (
        <Form colon={false}>
            {otFormItems}
        </Form>
    );
};

const HorizontalDocumentForm = Form.create({ name: 'login' })(AP);

export default HorizontalDocumentForm;

Here is the unit test written:
const initialStateOpenText = {
  landingScreen: {
    selectedApplication: '3',
    authenticatedUser: {
      email: 'adp9@gmail.com',
      groups: '000-AWs-ALL'
    },
    entityFunctionalAreas: [
      { entityId: 3, entityCode: 'opentext_usbl', name: 'OPENTEXT_USBL'}
    ],
    authServicePermissions: {
      userRoles: ['Document Operator', 'Document Admin'],
      userPermissions: {
        perm: [2, 9, 7, 5],
        access: [
          { entity: 2, fas: [1, 9], opcos: [86, 87, 104]},
          { entity: 1, fas: null, opcos: null},
          { entity: 3, fas: [], opcos: []}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  functionalAreas: {
    selectedFA: 'AP',
    selectedDocumentType: undefined,
    isLoadingCategories: false,
    hasFailedLoadingCategories: false,
    apFormValues: {
      [captureDate]: ['', ''],
      category: "1"
    },
    isSearching: false,
    categoryDoctypeMapping: [{categoryId: 1, categoryName: "Category 1"}, {categoryId: 2, categoryName: "Category2"}]
  }
};

it('should render initial Category field for Opentext Entity and update value on selection', async () => {
  MockHttpHandler.doGET = jest.fn().mockImplementation((url) => {
    if (url === config.apiBaseUrl + '/search-api/v1/entities/1/func-areas/1/categories') {
      return Promise.resolve([{categoryId: 1, categoryName: "Category 1"}, {categoryId: 2, categoryName: "Category2"}]);
    } else if (url === config.apiBaseUrl + '/search-api/v1/opcos') {
      return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
  });

  const { getByTestId, getByText, debug } = renderWithReduxAndThunk(<AP/>, initialStateOpenText);

  // Ensure the component is rendered
  await waitFor(() => {
    const categorySelector = getByTestId('ap-category-selector');
    expect(categorySelector).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // Open the dropdown
  fireEvent.mouseDown(getByTestId('ap-category-selector'));

  // Debug to check the current state of the document
  debug();

  // Wait for and select the category option
  await waitFor(() => {
    const categoryOption = getByText((content, element) => {
      return element && element.textContent === "Category2";
    });
    expect(categoryOption).toBeTruthy();
    fireEvent.click(categoryOption);
  });

  // Check if the value is updated
  await waitFor(() => {
    const categorySelector = getByTestId('ap-category-selector');
    expect(categorySelector).toHaveTextContent('Category2');
  });
});

Test failed with the below error:
    Unable to find an element with the text: (content, element) => {
          return element && element.textContent === "Category2";
        }. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

How can I reliably interact with the Ant Design dropdown options in my test? I've tried using getByText, but it seems unable to find the dropdown options. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
